# calling on didFinish does not work on my webview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am new to IOS/Swift, I am trying to listen to the didFinish event, but it is not getting called

```
    class MyWebView: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate {

    public var baseController : UIViewController?

    var linkOptions = [String: String]()


    @IBOutlet var web: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        web.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsMessageHandler")
        web.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsErrorMessageHandler")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let request = URLRequest(url: formatUrl())
        web.load(request)
        web.navigationDelegate = self
        web.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
    }

    func web(_ web: WKWebView, didFinish  navigation: WKNavigation!)
    {
        print("---Hitted URL--->") // here you are getting URL
    }
}
```

I have followed some examples online but none is working out for me.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the navigationDelegate before loading the request